# Entity framework core, binding result from query to model that is not part of contecx

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a question, ad cant find an answer, I am using an newest entity framework core, and in context I am having some models, all works fine when i bind results to one of those dbsets.

But now i have a custom model and i do not want to be  part of context, let say i need only one field from table (and basically i cant create another entity because i already have one that supports that table).

So i tried

```
            var second = new SqliteParameter { ParameterName = "@Second", SqliteType = SqliteType.Text, Value = timepoint.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") };
            var axm = new SqliteParameter { ParameterName = "@Axm", SqliteType = SqliteType.Text, Value = axmId };

            var query = @"select Id, ExtendedTimestamp, AxmCardId, SrcChannel, timestamp, CurrentData from currents where Timestamp = @Second and AxmCardId = @Axm and SrcChannel in (1, 2) and CorrectEntry = 1;";
            IQueryable<SourceCurrent> result = ctx.Set<SourceCurrent>().FromSql(query, second, axm);
```

But no luck, it tells me that it needs db set to populate. I know such thing was possible in Entity framework, but core version is a different thing as i know.

Comment: What about mapping the current DbsSet to another model who is not part from EF?

Comment: Currently (EF Core 2.0.2) it's not possible. You have to wait for [EF Core 2.1 Query Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types)

Comment: Oh well, I've just created second context for that cases :)